# HTMLTestRunner not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm giving it a try to Selenium+Python and after having researched a little bit about a nice way to generate a report I run into "HTMLTestRunner", the thing is that I've looked for a lot of examples on the internet and they're all the same however when I try to get it to work on my code (pressing play mostly), I can't see the report generated and I'm not getting any error , Can you giving me a hand please? 
This is the code I'm using:

```
class TestPruebaTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.verificationErrors = []

    def testName(self): #Some logic on the code passing driver to another class and return
        driverUtilizoPrueba = self.driver
        manejadorLogicaBMI = logicaBMI.logicaBMI(driverUtilizoPrueba,url)
        manejadorLogicaBMI.logicaPrograma()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()

    suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(TestPruebaTest))

    dateTimeStamp = time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S')

    buf = file("TestReport" + "_" + dateTimeStamp + ".html", "wb")

    runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(

             stream=buf,

             title='Test the Report',

             description='Result of tests'

             )

    runner.run(suite)
```

Comment: When you say "pressing play" do you mean in an IDE? I only ask as from my own experience, I would only generate the `html` file if your `main` is run from the command-line.

Comment: Yes I mean by my IDE, and yes obviuosly this will be run from the command line but in the mean time firstable I want to test it using the IDE because It's the place where I'm developing the features

Comment: Thanks for the info. I appreciate the frustration but what I meant, and perhaps wasn't clear enough on, is to test/debug your html output is that you should run it from the command-line, even during the test that you're writing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Install HTMLTestRunner-rv

```sh
pip install htmltestrunner-rv
```

```py
import time
import unittest

from runner import HTMLTestRunner


class TestPruebaTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print("setup")

    def testName(self):  # Some logic on the code passing driver to another class and return
        print("testcase")

    def tearDown(self):
        print("teardown")
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(TestPruebaTest))
    dateTimeStamp = time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S')
    runner = HTMLTestRunner(log=True,title='Test the Report',
                            description='Result of tests', open_in_browser=True)
    runner.run(suite)
```

[image: test report]